# What Linux version of Flash do I download?

Tags: flash, software-installation

I don't know what Linux version of Adobe Flash to install for Ubuntu 13.04; Also: once I get it, how do I install it?

Answer (score 2):

Start an terminal and add the Canonical partner repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

Then enter

```
apt-get update && sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

As alternative you can download the .deb file from Adobe.
First check the bit version you need.
Therefore open a terminal and enter

```
 uname  -m
```

Remember the x86_64 (so 64 bits address range) or x86 of the output.

```
http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/
```

Select *Linux (64/32)* (according to the output above)
and
*Flash_Player_11.2_for_Ubuntu_(apt)
and click *download*.

The Ubuntu Software Center will open and then you can install the "Adobe Flash Player plugin version 11" with a click onto the install button.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure since I don't have my Linux machine with me but try this.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install flash
```

(press tab twice list all the possibilities select the installer).